# Slides stacking under each other

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

So im trying to get a slider with different kinds of logo's but every plugin i install displays them under each other. im using wordpress.

The current plugin is Easy logo slider.

this is the link to the page: 
http://mjoosse.nl/partners/

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Comment: I guess your plugin not being called your html.

Answer (score 0):

You have a JavaScript error:

`ReferenceError: create_jcarousel is not defined` in your `/partners` page in this line:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>create_jcarousel('A7FvRB');</script>
```

This might break your page! Moreover some of the files cannot be loaded (e.g. `bootstrap.min.css`).

Since you are using Bootstrap, why not just go ahead and use their [`carousel`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) module?